# Microsoft-excel: If column G of row (of any row within the selection) is not empty, add character ❚ in front of column A and column G

Tags: excel, conditional-formatting

From this [website](https://www.exceltip.com/tips/add-a-character-to-every-cell.html), we can understand that we can obtain the `❚` in front of any number within the selection by using:

`\❚ #` as custom number formatting.

Can we adapt this to achieve the following:

---

### Example

Imagine this is the file:

[image]

This is what should be done:

[image]

---

Assumption: the only possibilities for cells in column G, to begin with are:

- blank
- a number

We are interested in when the cell for any given row in column G is not blank (= when it is a number).

---

So the question is:

- If cell of column G of row is not empty (and is a number, which ... let's assume automatically is the case)
- And if cell of column A **of that same row** is not empty (does not need to be a number)

⬇ Then ⬇

- Add character ❚ in front of cell in column A and cell in column G.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doable with the use of several conditional formatting rules:

1. Rule for column G (which is assumed to only contain numbers):

   - Formula: `=AND($G1<>"",$A1<>"")`
   - Custom number format: `❚ #`
2. First rule for column A (which can contain numbers or text):

   - Formula: `=AND($G1<>"",$A1<>"",ISNUMBER($A1))`
   - Custom number format: `❚ #`
3. Second rule for column A:

   - Formula: `=AND($G1<>"",$A1<>"",NOT(ISNUMBER($A1)))`
   - Custom number format: `❚ @`

In action:
[image]

Comment: OK, no worries. Perhaps it would easier with a macro? I am open to anything that achieves the result ;). I am still learning from your current answer.